# How to access a VM's server from my host with VMWare Workstation?

Tags: windows, networking, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I set up a VM with VMWare Workstation and started an HTTP server in it.

How can I send an HTTP request from my host's web browser now?
Does VMWare Workstation automatically assign an accessible local IP address when I boot up a guest?

Technical:

- Host: Windows 10 Pro 19042.867
- Guest: Linux Mint 20.1 Cinnamon
- VMWare Workstation Pro 16.1.0
- NAT Virtual Network Adapter (I am willing to change this option if it helps with my intention)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the regular method of connecting from one machine to another.  Default network here is NAT and so the guest machine will have an IP address on another subnet.  I usually use IP addressing when I connect machines like this that is, using NAT).

It might be easier for you to use Bridged Networking.  That way, the guest machine will have an IP from your router on the same subnet as your host machine.  This may make it easier to make the request.

Using Bridged Networking is just like using real machines on the same network and so should work fine.

I am using VMware Workstation 16.1.1 on a Windows 10 Pro Host.

Comment: What about this aspect of the question: “How can I send an HTTP request from my host's web browser now?” Seems like they might be using the VMs for web development.

Comment: If Bridged Networking is used, then Host talking to Guest is just like real machines. So I think that should work. We need to hear from the OP.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I used `ifconfig` on my Linux Mint guest to look up my local IP address, copied it to my host's browser (after adding the port to the ufw whitelist) and could connect without any problems. I just didn't expect it to be that easy. So I will stay with NAT for now. :)